# No output shown for human_time_diff

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `human_time_diff` to show how long ago something was posted.

I'm getting the ACF field like this:

```
<?php $commenttime = get_sub_field( 'time', $postid ); ?>
```

My return format for `$commenttime` is:

```
Y-m-d H:i:s
```

But when I do this, no time difference is shown:

```
<?php echo human_time_diff( $commenttime, current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Might help you out https://3v4l.org/Zr0M7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **`human_time_diff`: Determines the difference between two timestamps**

```
human_time_diff( $from, $to )
```

The use of this function

```
human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago';
```

Variable `$commenttime` should be in timestamp

```
strtotime($commenttime)
```